# Django rest framework updating nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, one with a foreignkey relationship to the other.  I am wanting to be able to create or update multiple entries at the same time.  I would not be creating and updating simultaneously.

I keep getting a bit confused about what is going on with people's examples.  I was hoping someone could not only show me what I need to do, but also give a bit of an explanation about what is going on at each step.  I'm specifically not understanding what the `validated_data.get()` method is doing, or what exactly is an instance, and what is being done with them.

```py
class ExtraFieldsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = ExtraFields
        fields = [
            'id',
            'job',
            'custom_data',
        ]


class JobWriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extra_fields = ExtraFieldsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [
            "extra_fields",
            "custom_data_fields",
        ]

    # Make JobSerializer able to create custom fields.
    def create(self, validated_data):
        extra_fields = validated_data.pop("extra_fields")
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.context['request'].user.id)
        client = Client.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
        new_job = Job.objects.create(user=user, client=client, **validated_data)
        new_job.save()
        for field in extra_fields:
            new_field = ExtraFields.objects.create(job=new_job, custom_data=field['custom_data'])
            new_field.save()
        return new_job

    # Make JobSerializer able to update custom fields
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you could probably use [drf-writeable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) for that, as it pretty much does exactly what you want.

But it never hurts to understand what's going on:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
        extra_fields = validated_data.pop("extra_fields")
        user = User.objects.get(id=self.context['request'].user.id)
        client = Client.objects.get(user=self.context['request'].user)
        new_job = Job.objects.create(user=user, client=client, **validated_data)
        new_job.save()
        for field in extra_fields:
            new_field = ExtraFields.objects.create(job=new_job, custom_data=field['custom_data'])
            new_field.save()
        return new_job
```

Since `JobWriteSerializer` is the parent serializer, we will start with that.
the `validated_data` argument that is passed to your create function contains, well, as the name suggests, the *validated data*. This means, you can assume that all the constraints you defined in your serializer (required fields, max_length, min_length etc) hold, and you don't need to check them.

The code looks fine, it seems you are popping all the `extra_fields` from your serializer and create `ExtraField` objects from them.
You specifically ask what's going on when using `validated_data.get` but you are using `validated_data.pop`. the difference is, that when using `get`, the retrieved data *stays* in the dictionary, while `pop` removes it.

This is especially handy for cases where you also have to create nested objects, consider this (some things omitted as they are not relevant):

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
  text = models.CharField(max_length=10, related_name='children')

class MyChildModel(models.Model):
  someVal = models.BooleanField()
  model = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)

class MyChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  someVal = serializers.BooleanField()  
   
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  text = serializers.TextField(...)
  childen = ChildrenSerializer(many=True)
  
  def create(self, validated_data):
     children = validated_data.pop('children', []) #POP!
     instance = super().create(validated_data)
     
     for c in children:
       MyChildSerializer.objects.create(model=instance, **c)
     return instance
```

You can test this yourself, if you use `get` instead of `pop` here, your serializer will rightfully complain that there are `children` objects inside the `validated_data` object, and drf cannot create nested relations out of the box. When you `pop` them, the serializer does not have those fields anymore and it works.

Note that this approach would not be efficient for your case, as you manually pass data to your `Job` object (like the `user` and the `client`) which you do not get via the passed data, but from your request. You can, if you want, get around that by using `get_serializer_context`, but lets just say that this is out of the questions scope.

On to your update method, I suggest something like that (not tested, but you get the idea):

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
  extra_fields = validated_data.pop('extra_fields', []) # POP the extra fields
  instance = super().update(instance, validated_data) # !!!!!

  for extra in extra_fields:
    #retrieve your extra fields and update them
    myExtra = ExtraFields.objects.get(id=extra['id])
    ....
```

The passed argument `instance` is actually the already existing instance of your `Job` model. This is the object you want to update. Note that again, I popped the `extra_fields`, precisely for doing what I described above: I used drf itself to modify/update the object, since I only have to implement the `update` for the child elements.

Comment: I was asking the questions about the update method, as I already understand the create method.  Every example I saw of the update method being overridden has made copies of parts of the instance, but they also use validate_data.  I was wondering about the `get` method because I assumed you could access it just like a dict.

Comment: and I showed you a possible way of writing your update method. You *can* access this like a normal dict, get/pop simply provide the convenience of providing a default argument if the key is not present.

Comment: Okay, I now see what is going on with the examples.  Thanks